# How can I share array lists between activities in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to build an android app and I have a problem. First of all, I wrote a method which access your phone memory and imports an excel file which contains two columns with values that represents time and heart rate. I read the data from excel and stored it into an array list and this array list it is
`DataFitbit` type (`DataFitbit` is a class I made which contains two parameters, like excel file, time and heart rate). Now I want to create a chart with this data in other activity, but I think the code wrote in order to share my arraylist between those two activities doesn't work. I don't have any error, but when I push the button that create another activity where I want to create the chart, the app crashes.

This is the code wrote in order to share the array list between activities:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
ArrayList<DateFitbit> dateFitbit = (ArrayList<DateFitbit>) bundle.get("arraylist");
ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
ArrayAdapter<DateFitbit> items = new ArrayAdapter<DateFitbit>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
listView.setAdapter(items);
```

The code that opens a new activity which will contain charts is:

```
public void openChartActivity(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChartActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("arraylist",dateFitbit);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

In the very first time I tried to see my data into a list view, to be sure that the share has been done, but as I said, something doesn't work well.

Do you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: Please share the exception message.

Comment: 2020-05-25 19:19:14.396 19141-19141/com.example.nuthealth E/ImportActivity: verifMem: NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION Attempt to get length of null array

Comment: 2020-05-25 19:18:47.856 19141-19141/com.example.nuthealth E/Minikin: Could not get cmap table size!

Comment: 2020-05-25 19:18:47.855 19141-19167/com.example.nuthealth E/MemoryLeakMonitorManager: MemoryLeakMonitor.jar is not exist!

Comment: When I press the button that create the new activity, where I want to create the chart, appear some errors, but I can't read them, because it disappears.

Comment: Does `DataFitbit` implement `Parcelable`?

Comment: No. It implements serializable

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing a basic `String` `ArrayList`, instead you're using a custom data type object for `ArrayList`.

For that to work, you need to do something as mentioned here:
1. Now, pass it in intent as:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("arraylist",(Serializable) dateFitbit);
intent.putExtra("Bundle",bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

2. In the receiving activity, get it as:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("Bundle");
ArrayList<DataFitBit> dateFitbit= (ArrayList<DataFitBit>) bundle.getSerializable("arraylist");
```

This will preserve your custom ArrayList model and you can then utilize it as you prefer.

Comment: @DenisaMărginean And what's the error or issue that didn't work?

Comment: Have you tried adding `implemenrs java.io.Serializable` in your `DataFitBit` class?

Comment: I tried it and now it doesn't crash anymore, but the receving activity is empty.

Comment: When I say that the app crashed I mean: when I press the button that creates the receiving activity my screen becomes white and the it returns to the previous activity